# How is AWS cost explorer calculate report for EC2 instances by billing tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I want to attach billing tag to my EC2 resources, but I have one question. Is it needed to add billing tag to attached volumes and IP addresses? Or in Cost Explorer I can see full price if will attach tag only for EC2 instances, it also will include the price for IPs and volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from someone who works in Amazon:

When you attach a tag for EC2 instance it will also include the price for any EBS Volume that's 'attached' to that instance and Elastic IP address 'associated' with that Instance.

If you have an EBS Volume not attached to the Instance and an Elastic IP address not associated with the Instance, the charges will show only for EC2 Instance only.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those resources are billed separately.

You will need to add an appropriate tag to the Amazon EBS volumes. I'm not sure whether an Elastic IP address can be tagged, but there is no charge if it is attached to a running EC2 instance.